# Is it safe to use `basename` with __FILE__?

Tags: c++, c, posix

The title is pretty clear: Is it safe to use `basename` (`man 3 basename`) with `__FILE__` ?.

---

It compiles and *seems* to work fine, **but** `basename`'s argument is `char*` (not `const char*`) and the `man`-page says:

> Both dirname() and basename() may modify the contents of path, so it may be desirable to pass a copy when calling one of these functions.

So, this makes me worry.

Maybe the question should be more like: what is the type of `__FILE__`? Isn't it a string literal / `const char*`? But if it is, why there's no a compile-time error (`const char*` to `char*`)?

Comment: It is a string literal. It is unsafe.

Comment: The question is, what do you want from it. Contents of this macro is not standartized. Generally smells XY problem.

Comment: `__FILE__` has no type. The preprocessor will simply fill that source with some `"/file/name.cpp"` string literal. So you will be doing `basename("string, probably located in read-only data section")` ( = when C/C++ compiler will get to that line and parse it).

Comment: @Ped7g Every value has a type.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, but that is the string `"... some file name ..."` which will be turned into value with some type by compiler. Not `__FILE__`, that one will be not even seen by compiler (unless you run it intentionally without preprocessing step).

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Actually every object has a(n effective) type and a value. A string literal is an object (not just a value).

Comment: @Ped7g the type of a string literal is `char[N]; /* N just large enough for all the characters in the literal plus the terminating NUL */`. See [Standard 6.4.5p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6).

Comment: @pmg you are missing my point. It's type of the string literal, not type of `__FILE__` macro itself. Preprocessor doesn't recognize types, it operates with strings only, substituting them.

Comment: @Ped7g: what the compiler will see is `basename("/home/user/example.c")`. The preprocessor does not care about `basename()`, the compiler never sees `__FILE__`.

Comment: See also Boost::FileSystem / [std::filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read *carefully* [basename(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html) and notice:

> Warning: there are *two* different functions `basename()` - see below.

and take care of the *NOTES* saying

> There are two different versions of `basename()` - the POSIX version
>   described above, and the GNU version, which one gets after
>
> ```
>       #define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
>       #include <string.h>
> ```
>
> The GNU version **never modifies** its argument, and returns the empty
>   string when path has a trailing slash

<sup>(emphasis is mine)</sup>

Because it is said that the GNU version does not modify its argument, using it is safe with `__FILE__`

BTW, you could consider customizing your GCC (e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)) to define some `__builtin_basename` which would compute the basename at compile time if given a string literal like `__FILE__` or else invoke `basename` at runtime.

Notice that `libgen.h` has `#define basename    __xpg_basename`

Comment: You only get the POSIX version if you include `<libgen.h>` AFAICS; see [POSIX specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/basename.html) for details. The GNU version is the default one if using glibc.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question (the part with the 2 versions). As for the (nice) GCC trick - I use `cmake` and the code must be compatible at least with `gcc` **and** `clang`.

Answer (score 5):

> what is the type of __FILE__? Isn't it a string literal / const char*?

Yes. It's a string literal.

> But if it is, why there's no a compile-time error (const char* to char*)?

Possibly because the implementation you use (glibc's) may be returning a pointer within the string literal you pass (i.e. it doesn't modify its input).
In any case, you can't rely on it for the above stated below.

C standard (c11, § 6.10.8.1) says the `__FILE__` is a string literal:

> `__FILE__` The presumed name of the current source ﬁle (a character string siteral).

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/basename.html) says:

> The basename() function may **modify the string pointed to by path**,
>   and may return a pointer to internal storage. The returned pointer
>   might be invalidated or the storage might be overwritten by a
>   subsequent call to basename().

(emphasis mine).

So, no, it's not safe to call `basename()` with `__FILE__`. You can simply take a copy of `__FILE__` and do `basename()` on it:

```
char *filename = strdup(__FILE__);
if (filename) {
    /* error */
}
char *file_basename = basename(filename);
free(filename);
```

---

Since `__FILE__` is a string literal, using an *array* is another option:

```
char filename[] = __FILE__;
char *file_basename = basename(filename);
```

Comment: Why `strdup`? Just allocate a local buffer... `char filename[]=__FILE__`.

Comment: Indeed. Updated the answer.

Comment: The idea with the array is interesting, I like it.